# When is Br(X) = H^2(X,G_m)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, brauer-groups

In Milne, Étale cohomology, it is proved that $\mathrm{Br}(X) = H^2(X,\mathbf{G}_m)$ for $X$ regular of dimension $\leq 2$. Are there in the meantime further results for $X$ regular?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When $X$ is quasi-projective over an affine scheme (or more generally if $X$ has an ample [**EDIT:** invertible] sheaf), then its Brauer group is isomorphic to the **torsion part** of $H^2(X, {\mathbb G}_m)$. This is an unpublished result of Gabber, and J. de Jong [wrote down a different proof](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~dejong/papers/2-gabber.pdf).

Comment: Are there criteria when $H^2(X,\mathbf{G}_m)$ is torsion free?

Comment: In Lichtenbaum, Zeta-Functions of Varieties Over Finite Fields at s = 1, he proves that it is torsion for varieties over finite fields.

Comment: You mean X has an ample line bundle? 

Comment: It is torsion for $X$ regular, Noetherian: Consider $0 \to \mathbf{G}_m \to j_*\mathbf{G}_m \to Div_X \to 0$ and the long exact sequence; since $X$ is regular, we have $Div_X = \oplus_{x \in X^{(1)})i_{x,*}\mathbf{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

Dear norondion: It appears to me from your comments to Qing Liu's answer that you are interested in when this cohomological Brauer group is actually $0$. If that is true, then these two related MO questions (and Emerton's answer to one of them) may be of interest:

[Two conjectures by Gabber](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7537/two-conjectures-by-gabber-on-brauer-and-picard-groups).

[Flat cohomology and Picard groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10501/flat-cohomology-and-picard-groups).

(Of course, the punctured spectrum of a regular local ring is a regular scheme. Also, you can probably get some statements for projective $X$ by looking at the local ring of the cone over $X$). My apology if this is not relevant.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I'm interested in cases where it is finite.